# Crystal Reports Like Details sections in SSRS 2008 R2 Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

As part of a project I am working on, I am developing a rather long report that is to be printed out by the user at the end of a process. The report, when printed, ranges from 10-20 pages long. In Report Builder, I have the sections of the report separated in rectangles. This works fine, unless I need to adjust the spacing between the rectangles. Then, I have to adjust any rectangles below the one I changed as well.

In SAP Crystal Reports 2012, you can use Details sections to handle this. I would place each rectangle in a Details section, then I could easily resize that section and everything else would automatically adjust.

Is there any way to replicate this behavior in SSRS? It's important to note that I have page breaks and other formatting settings set on the rectangles. It's very time consuming to manually adjust these rectangles to maintain my formatting.

EDIT:
In essence, is there a way to split the report body into multiple sections like you can in Crystal Reports?

EDIT2:
I've created a gif that shows my dilemma. You can view it here on [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rQr0.jpg). As you can see, when I resize the uppermost rectangle, it overlaps with the lower two rectangles and I have to manually move them down. On a report that consist of 20+ unique sections, this can be quite tedious. In CR, this can be avoided using Details sections as described above. Is there any way to avoid this in SSRS other than uses a table / list?

Comment: It might help if you sketched a mock-up of the overall report layout and which part is causing issues. I've not used Crystal for about 20 years so I can't picture what you are comparing to but if I seethe problem I might be able to suggest a better option. It may be that you've attacked the report like you are used to in CR which might not be the best way in SSRS.

Comment: Actually, I've never used CR to make a report. I just know it has this functionality since I've had to recreated some CR reports in SSRS. I don't really think a mock-up would help, as it's not a specific issue, but I'll try to put something together and update the question.

Comment: OK. I just can't visualise  what you're trying to achieve and a mock-up may help me and/or other people find a solution.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I've added a gif that shows the problem. Let me know if you need anymore information and I'll add it. I think that shows the issue fairly well though.

Comment: OK, I understand now, thanks. If you need to put the tables in rectangles then I'm not sure you can do it. Normally you would not use rectangles and simply stack the tables on top of each other, if the top dataset grows, the table will expand and the others will get pushed down automatically, only the gap between them stays consistent.

Comment: Unfortunately the content within the rectangles requires them to be in one to print correctly.. each section contains tables, growable textboxes, and other content. Oh well. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If the content of each is the same (structurally) then subreports might be the answer. Build a report that just contains the contents of one rectangle, add a list to your main report and insert the subreport int the lists 'cell'. It very similar to Brandons answer but using a subreport means you only have to resize a single report. The main report contains a dataset to drive the list from which you can pass parameters to the subreport if required.

Comment: It is fairly similar and I had considered using subreports, but I decided against again because each section pulls some data from a shared dataset. Although, at this point, I think I'd be better off doing subreports and passing in the few fields needed as parameters. Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is doable in SSRS. To my knowledge, you only really have one option.

You can create a single column table or list and put each rectangle in a row of the table. Then, you can resize the rows as needed and the rest of the table will automatically adjust.  I don't know if this will work with page breaks though.

You'll also have to set a dataset for the list, which may affect any tables or other databound controls that are in the report.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks for the validation, though. I'm going to mark this as best answer, but if someone knows of a better way then I'll change it.